# How to make <a> tag clickable of html in UWP Webview?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

Here i am working with Xaml & C#. and i am using a webview to show some html, its working perfect but there is a problem i am facing is that how to make  tag clickable of that Html content.

Thanks for any Help in Advance.

Comment: What do you mean "how to make <a> tag clickable of that Html content"?  Do you want to navigate to another website when clicking the content in  <a> tag? Or you want to execute some code? Please provide more details about your question. A [mcve] would be better.

Comment: Actually the thing is that i am loading an html page in my webview and that html contains an <a> tag from which i want to navigate on other page of my app. for example - i have an article detail page (Html is loaded in Webview), where i want to link author name with profile detail page is one of the another page of my app.

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT Actually it means Author name is in html is loaded in webview and i want to navigate on other page (Author Profile Detail Page) of app whenever someone click on author name.

Comment: Could you share some code about the <a> tag in your html? Do you have the control of this html page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we click an `<a>` tag in `WebView`, [WebView.NavigationStarting event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigationstarting.aspx) will be triggered. And in this event, we can get a [`WebViewNavigationStartingEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webviewnavigationstartingeventargs.aspx) which contains the URI in `<a>` tag. So I think you can use this to navigate to your Author Profile Detail Page. As I don't know how your `<a>` tag implements. Here I just use a simple demo for example.

In XAML code:

```xml
<WebView NavigationStarting="WebView_NavigationStarting" 
         Source="https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/07/13/introducing-new-remote-sensing-features-2/" />
```

In code-behind:

```cs
private void WebView_NavigationStarting(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationStartingEventArgs args)
{
    //Add some logic to determine if we need to navigate to AuthorProfileDetailPage
    //and which author's profile need to be shown
    if (args.Uri.AbsoluteUri == @"https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/author/windowsappsteam/")
    {
        //Cancel the navigataion in WebView
        args.Cancel = true;
        //Navigate to AuthorProfileDetailPage with the parameter
        //in AuthorProfileDetailPage we can use this parameter to determine which author's profile need to be shown
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(AuthorProfileDetailPage), args.Uri.Segments.Last());
    }
}
```

This is a simple sample, you can implement the logic by yourself. Hope this helps.

Comment: Many Many Thanks for your help. now it is working perfectly.

Comment: i am voting it up but it is Notifying that i have reputation less then 15.